# d3 fill under interpolated line

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

In the following d3 line chart [example](http://bl.ocks.org/jhubley/17aa30fd98eb0cc7072f), I would like to fill in the the area under the lines with fill color equivalent to line color and a transparency of 50%.

In addition to adding area to the CSS

```
.area {
  fill: blue;
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

adding the following to `function updateGraph(data)`

```
    svg.append("path")
   .data([data])
   .attr("class", "area")
   .attr("d", area);
```

and

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value); });
```

what is needed for the filled in area to fit under the interpolated line and for fill color to be equivalent to line color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you have to create a **new** selection before the lines' selection (named `states`), here named `stateArea`:

```
var stateArea = svg.selectAll(".area")
    .data(result, function(d) {
        return d.key
    });

stateArea.enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "area");

stateArea.transition()
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return d.color = color(d.key);
    })
    .style("opacity", 0.5)
    .attr("id", function(d) {
        return 'tagArea' + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    })
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        return area(d.values)
    });

stateArea.exit().remove();
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/0c80f4f72247dcc8f590aa2d63d40da0

PS: I'm just appending the areas here, you'll have to refactor the code if you want that legend to the left changing the areas as well.